# Mac Python IDLE Autocomplete/Pop-up not working

Tags: macos, autocomplete, popup, python-idle

total beginner in Python here. I installed Python 3.6.5 on my Mac and I am using the default IDLE. When I did VBA or Java (long time ago), there used to be pop-up help/completion suggestions after you typed "." (for example).

How do I make it happen in IDLE?

EDIT// There is another thread asking essentially the same question however,  it is six years old. I did not want to ressurect such an old thread since a lot has changed, I assume.

Bottom Line:
Is it possible to have an "interactive help" pop up as I am typing using the IDE which came with Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python IDLE. Auto-complete/Show completions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089476/python-idle-auto-complete-show-completions-not-working)

Comment: Edited for more clarity. Essentially, I am missing the autocomplete pop-ups that for example pyCharm offers. If IDLE is doing it as default, then mine's not working, I guess. Thanks for any tips on how to make it work.

Comment: The 'default IDLE' would normally mean the IDLE that is part of the default Python 2.7, installed by Apple.  So I am not sure which version you run.  For auto completions, read https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html#completions.  Note " Run the module once with your imports".  When I write a module, I tend to run it multiple times to check for errors as I go.  So the 'possible completions' list gets constantly updated.  Aside: Upgrading to 3.6.6 should not affect completions, but it has some other IDLE changes.  This is currently true of most every maintenance release.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this apply to 3.6.5 but here is a solution to 3.7.

- MacOS 10.14.4
- Python 3.7.3
- Installed from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-373/)
- Tk version: 8.6.8

Test if this is your problem:

If you type `str(` you should see a calltip explaining str. (e.i.`str(object='') -> str`).

However if you type `str.(tab)` and **don't** see a window, then this worked for me.

---

Go to the file `autocomplete_w.py`. You can find the file path by:

```
>>> import idlelib.autocomplete_w
>>> idlelib.autocomplete_w
/the/path/to/autocomplete_w.py
```

(The default path is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/idlelib/autocomplete_w.py`)

And in this file add line 200:

```
197        scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
198        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
199        listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

200        acw.update_idletasks() ##### ADD THIS to fix the autocomplete

201        acw.lift()  #...
```

Comment: No, didn't work for me, unfortunately. It must be my machine. But thanks for the fix as it might help someone else.

Comment: This behavior may also have something to do with the OS version. Are you on the latest OS? You may want to try a fresh install of 3.6.5 from python.org and try this fix again.

Comment: Matt, thanks for the tip. I will try to do that. If I don't respond, it worked ;)

Comment: This edit worked for me running Python 3.7.3 in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/`

Comment: Did not work for me running Python 3.7.4 (v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 14:54:52) on OS X 10.13.6

Comment: Interesting. I notice you have a different version # than me. v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12

Answer (score 1):

When I run Idle I use the tab key for autocompletion.  If I type pri for example, and then hit tab key, pri becomes print. If there are multiple commands tab key opens a pop-up for you to chose.